# MVC4 How to configure different layouts & CSS for areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an MVC4 web app and have created 2 areas. I cannot see how to use different layouts for them. When I created the areas there was not a shared folder generated for them, 
I have tried creating one in the area named BO and copying the _layout.cshtml file there, no luck. Copied the _viewstart.cshtml file there,
renamed the _layout.cshtml to and changed the layout call in the BO area's _viewstart.cshtml to

```
Layout = ~/Areas/BO/Shared/Views/_BOLayout.cshtml";
```

still no luck, neither the layout nor the css & JS files are loading when I navigate to the BO area home page.
Lots of stuff around on making areas use the root _layout.cshtml but I cannot find much on using different ones for each area. Any suggestions please?

PS. The above (Copied the _viewstart.cshtml file there) also breaks things; I get: Type 'ASP._Page_Areas_BO__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'. Error on navigating to the area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following structure should work for an `Admin` area for example:

`~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

`~/Areas/Admin/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

`~/Areas/Admin/Views/Foo/Index.cshtml`:

```
<h2>Index view of FooController in Admin area</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! from your answer I realised 2 errors; I had "Shared/Views/" instead of "Views/Shared/", and the _viewstart.cshtml was in the root of the area. Corrected path and moved _viewstart.cshtml into the Shared folder in the area and it works fine. Thank you.